# How to make a recursive function c++?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'am trying to work with a multi-dimensional array in c++. I made a program that runs this array from one corner to another only on certain sequences, but I have no idea how to transform this code in a recursive function.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream f("2.in");
ofstream g("2.out");

int A[21][21],n,m,D[21][21],S[21][21];

int main()
{
    f>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            f>>A[i][j];
    //number of ways
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--)
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            if(i==n || j==1) D[i][j]=1;
            else D[i][j]=D[i][j-1]+D[i+1][j-1]+D[i+1][j];
    g<<D[1][n]<<endl;
    //max_summ
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--)
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            S[i][j]=A[i][j]+max(max(S[i][j-1],S[i+1][j-1]),S[i+1][j]);
    g<<S[1][n]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
----------------
2.in file
----------------
3
1 2 3 
-1 3 4
2 -1 -1
----------------
```

How could I make a recursive function for `number of ways` and `max_summ`?

Comment: Well, you'll need a function that isn't `main`. Gotta start somewhere.

Comment: @Cristian Describe in the function what the program tries to do.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow so , i tried to go through the array from a corner to another using only directions of North , North-East and East , and count number of ways of how i can go to that corner, and at the same time calculate the max sum of these ways .

Comment: @Cristian The problem you are trying to solve should be state differently. What is maximum value that is obtainable at right upper point in matrix going from top left one. And answer is simple: it is current_val + max(val_S, val_SW, val_E), where val_S is score to reach south neighbor from origin. So at each point you need to call your function at least three times to get other results (from the neighbor fields). How to get their results... call for them function another three times... It can be of course optimize to save those intermediate values, but you should see recursion pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about to concept of a recursive function, here's a simple example. It will count down to 0 from 3, or whatever number you call it on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int counting(int x){
   cout << x << endl;
   if(x>0) x = counting(--x);
   return x;
}

int main(){
   counting(3);
}
```